# integral inequality $\int_0^a \left(\frac{f(x)}{2x}\right)^2 dx \le \int_0^a (f'(x))^2 dx$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math

Let $f:[0,a]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous differentiable function satisfying $f(0)=0$. Prove the following inequality

$$\int_0^a \left(\frac{f(x)}{2x}\right)^2 dx \le \int_0^a (f'(x))^2 dx$$

Comment: I had an idea. I found that
$$\sqrt{x}\left(\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\right)'=f'(x)-\frac{f(x)}{2x}$$

but i can't finish it since the integral is improper.

Comment: Interesting problem! May I know the source? This vaguely reminds me of [Wirtinger's Inequality.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions)

Comment: @Prism The Wirtinger's inequality concerns the periodic functions as I understand from your link.

Comment: @YoshuaYonatan and how did you find the expression that you wrote in the comments, if I may ask?

Comment: @Prism , this is exercise for IMC preparation from the lecturer

Comment: @rbm I want to write $f'(x)$ and $\frac{f(x)}{2x}$ at the single equation

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note $f(0)=0\Rightarrow\int_0^x 2f(y)f^{\prime}(y)\;\mathbb{d}y=f^2(x)$ for any $x>0$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^a \Big(\frac{f(x)}{2x}\Big)^2\;\mathbb{d}x&=&\int_0^a\int_0^x\Big(\frac{1}{2x}\Big)^2\cdot 2f(y)f^{\prime}(y)\;\mathbb{d}y\mathbb{d}x\\ &=&\int_0^af(y)f^{\prime}(y)\int_y^a\frac{1}{2x^2}\;\mathbb{d}x\mathbb{d}y\\ &=&\int_0^af(y)f^{\prime}(y)\cdot \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{a})\;\mathbb{d}y\\ &=&\int_0^af^{\prime}(x)\cdot \frac{f(x)}{2}(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a})\;\mathbb{d}x
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Now apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\Big(\int_0^af^{\prime}(x)\cdot \frac{f(x)}{2}(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a})\;\mathbb{d}x
 \Big)^2 &\le& \int_0^a\big(f^{\prime}(x)\big)^2\;\mathbb{d}x
\cdot \int_0^a\Big(\frac{f(x)}{2}(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a})\Big)^2\;\mathbb{d}x\\ &\le& \int_0^a\big(f^{\prime}(x)\big)^2\;\mathbb{d}x
\cdot \int_0^a\Big(\frac{f(x)}{2x}\Big)^2\;\mathbb{d}x
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Based on the above, we obtain
$$
\Big(\int_0^a \Big(\frac{f(x)}{2x}\Big)^2\;\mathbb{d}x \Big)^2\le \int_0^a \Big(\frac{f(x)}{2x}\Big)^2\;\mathbb{d}x\cdot \int_0^a\big(f^{\prime}(x)\big)^2\;\mathbb{d}x
$$
Then we get the desired result.